# Changing a view's initialization based on properties

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview

I am trying to build an approach to initialize a view dynamically with different components. Hence, I need to do this on the fly at initialization time. I was thinking of having a struct with default values, and if at any given time the `BOOL` property of enabling changes, I can reload the input views.

Hence I can loop through the `BOOL` properties and check if something have changed. Is there a better way of doing this, or does that sound about right?

The architecture:

UIView -> Buttons 1 to 10 laid equally in distance. Based on users preference, the button can be turned on/off, however by default they are all on.

Comment: This is really unclear -- you want to change a view, "on the fly", but when it's being intialized? That's what you do when you initialize an object -- you set up its values. Can you mock up some (pseudo)code to provide a more concrete explanation?

Comment: So here is my concern, why can't I use some struct values to construct my initialization of objects? And check for any changes occurred using KVO to see if the value have changed and re-construct my view based on that. Essentially, the initialization occurs through for loop, than manual initialization as I have many buttons to initialize. Or if there is any better trick than that, that would be great to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use key value coding observer to identify when a value has changed. This could be your trigger to do the necessary update. Polling a boolean value for changes is an unnecessary step and might cause your app to become unresponsive. Also, evaluate if the action that causes the necessity to update/change the view is an action, then you can just implement the changes inside the proper action. For more information, check the Key-Value Observing Programming Guide : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: hi J2theC, I had thought about it, but the main reason of getting BOOL into the picture was due to using for loop over "BOOL Type", and fill my view based on which bool's are set on/off